# SQL Server Login Failed for User SA

Tags: sql-server, sa

I just logged in to SQL Server 2005 with SQL Server Authentication but was stuck at the error message saying "Login failed for user ‘sa’, (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)". What happened to this?

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server Management studio right click in Object Explorer and ensure in the server properties - under Security the option "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" is enabled

If you are accessing the SQL Box remotely ensure the TCP/IP setting is enabled in SQL Server configuration manager.

Answer (score 1):

**Three things to check if you can't log in to SQL Server using the sa account:**

1.Check the password and provide a new one if necessary

```
sp_password NULL, 'mypassword', 'sa'
```

2.Enable the sa account

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE
```

3.Check that the sa account is not being affected by the domain security policy

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='yourpassword',CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

Comment: The option 3 works for me while using a T4 template and SMO. Thank you.